# If $f(x)f''(x)\le0$, and $f(a)=0$, can we comment about the sign of $f(a+h)f''(a-h)$?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

**Question:**

Let $f:R\to R$ is a differentiable function such that all successive derivatives exist. $f'(x)$ can be zero at discrete points only and $f(x)f''(x)\le0\; \forall\; x\in \mathrm R$.

- If $f(a)=0$ then which of the following is correct?

a)$\;f(a+h)f''(a-h)<0 $

b)$\;f(a+h)f''(a-h)>0$

c)$\;f'(a+h)f''(a-h)<0$

d)$\;f'(a+h)f''(a-h)<0$

- If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two consecutive roots of $f(x)=0$ then, for $\alpha< c < \beta$

a)$\;f''(c)=0$

b)$\;f'''(c)=0$

c)$\;f''''(c)=0$

d)$\;f''''(c)=0$

**My Attempt:**

For the first one I took it as $y=\sin x$ graph and could get the answer. But I want to know the proper solution using calculus and all I could get was that $f(x)$ and $f''(x)$ have opposite signs so the inflection would keep switching like a sine curve.

For the second one I have no idea how to even start.

I tried my hardest to solve these for like an hour and still no help. Please help me out.

**Note:** $h\gt0$ is a very small quantity. $a$ is a point in the domain.

Comment: What are $a$ and $h$?

Comment: Try to define the terms you're looking at more thoroughly. Is $x=a$ the point at which it's known that $f(x)\cdot f^{\prime\prime}(x)<0$? What is known of $h$ (for example, does the problem require that "for all sufficiently small $h$" the one of the following occurs)? How is $c$ defined beyond $\alpha<c<\beta$ (properties hold for all such $c$? For at least one such "c"?)

Comment: Extremely sorry, h is not specified as being a very small quantity its any value and f(a)=0 is given I just edited it, my bad.

Comment: Also the answers are B,B

Comment: @JonathanY. Is the question clear now?

Comment: @UmbertoP. I have made an edit.

Comment: @aarbee Actually not. But I see that an answer already explains the reason.

Comment: @JonathanY. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

ALL possible answers are incorrect! Because for $f(x)=-x$

$(a=0)$ we get $f'(x)=-1$ (nowhere zero), $f''(x)=0$ and

clearly $f(x)f''(x)=0\leq0$. But $a)=0\,\, b)=0\,\, c)=0\,\, d)=0$. Therefore

under the given assumptions ALL answers can be wrong!

For the second question now, take $f(x)=(x-1)^{3}(x+1)^{2}$. Then the two consecutive roots are $-1$ and $+1$. Take $c=0$.

We get $f''(x)=4(5x^{3}-3x^{2}-3x+1)$ and clearly $f''(0)=4\neq 0$.

$f'''(x)=12(5x^{2}-2x-1)$ and $f'''(0)=-12\neq\,0$ and

$f''''(x)=24(5x-1)$ and $f''''(0)=-24\neq\,0$.

Thus again all possible answers are incorrect!

Now if the assumption about $c$ refers to the existence of $c$, then we also have an inconclusive answer, For instance take $f(x)=sinx$ and two consecutive roots $0$ and $\pi$. Then $f''(x)=-sinx$ and there is NO $c\in (0,\pi)$ such that $f''(c)=0.$

However, if we take $f(x)=sin^{2}x$ and  $0$ and $\pi$ two consecutive roots, then $f''(x)=2cos2x$ and there is a $c\in(0,\pi)$, $c=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ such that $f''(c)=0$.

In other words a) can neither be rejected or accepted!

Now we go to b) and consider $f(x)=x^{2}(x-1)$ and $0$ and $1$ the consecutive roots. $f'(x)=3x^{2}-2x$, $f''(x)=6x-2$, $f'''(x)=6\neq0$ for all $x$.

Now we go to c) and consider $f(x)=x^{3}(x-1)$, $0$ and $1$ the consecutive roots. $f'(x)=4x^{3}-3x^{2}$, $f''(x)=12x^{2}-6x$, $f'''(x)=24x-6$, $f''''(x)=24\neq\,0$ for all $x$.!!

Comment: Please mind $a+h, a-h$, thus option B is correct not A

Comment: Many Thanks! I will change the example!